# How does capturing work in gipf?

Tags: gipf

I'm unclear as to when pieces are captured vs. when they're moved to the repository in Basic Gipf

If I understand it correctly, the 4+ in a row pieces are moved to the repository of the player with their color. Any pieces that extend this line are dealt with as follows:

- if they're the same color as the current player, they're moved back to the repository
- if they're the other player's color, they're captured.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is mostly correct. However, the player who picks up the pieces is not the current player, but the player who owns the 4+ pieces in a row.

> **E. Taking Pieces**
>
> 1. As soon as 4 pieces of the same color are lined up next to each other, they must be taken from the board by the one playing with that color. Moreover, not only must these 4 pieces be removed, but also all of the pieces that form a direct extension of them. The pieces of one's own color are returned to the reserve, the pieces of the other color are captured, thus lost for the opponent.
> 2. As soon as 4 pieces of the same color are lined up, it is compulsory to remove them from the board (included the pieces extending the row), no matter who created the row. The color of the pieces in a row determines which player must take them. One's own pieces are returned to the reserve, the opponent's pieces are captured.

A copy of the rules can be found [here](http://www.gipf.com/gipf/rules/complete_rules.html).

Comment: I've read the rules, but the difference between the 4 in a row and the other stones wasn't completely clear. Now it is, thank you.